# Issue Using QTP on a VB.NET application with dialog

Tags: automated-tests, qtp, qtplugin

I have a VB.NET application with a dialog. With HP QTP I've recorded the following script:

```
 1.   Dialog("CDRCreator1.1").WinButton("OK").Click
 2.   SwfWindow("CDRCreator").SwfButton("Select System").Click
 3.   SwfWindow("CDRCreator").SwfWindow("Dialog1").SwfComboBox("ComboBox1").Select "VALUE01"
 4.   SwfWindow("CDRCreator").SwfWindow("Dialog1").SwfButton("OK").Click
 5.   SwfWindow("CDRCreator").Close
```

The script clicks on a button provoking the opening of a dialog box (point 2).
All the operations (3. and 4.) go correctly on, by the dialog box.
But then QTP stucks because seemes to return on step 3. for some reason, but the dialog box is not present yet.

Have you got any suggestion on haw solve it?
Thank you.

Comment: Easy thing to do is to increase the Object Sync Time.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I am not providing the exact solution but I am just giving the  possibilities, which I think looking at your code you should try out.

**First things first:**
Please run it in debug mode and check whether the execution is going back to 3rd step or its just stuck at the 4th step, I don't think execution ever goes back to previous step unless its started right over from first line or kept in loop.

To do this, keep a breakpoint at step 2, when execution comes and stops at breakpoint line, press F11 and check the flow of execution.

Similar kind of post with different add-ins but same issue as yours
http://community.hpe.com/t5/Unified-Functional-Testing/QTP-stuck-in-execution/td-p/4730300

Make sure that proper add-ins are loaded while identifying objects and executing the application.
Try with Java,ActiveX and .Net add-ins.

Sorry still no reps to comment so trying to help you out by writing as an answer

Comment: Thank you for you answer. The problem is quite strange; you right that the execution doesn't go back. It stucks at 4th steps because the selection of value in the combo box at step 3 also close the dialog so the 4th step is useless. But when you act manually, the behaviour is different and you need to click on the "OK" button to close the dialog. Any idea?

Comment: Not sure why that would happen. Did you try selecting the value in dropdown and then clicking somewhere else on the Diaog box(i.e click somewhere in free area and not on the OK button).